# How to delete a list item from ant design List?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to show a list of data in ant design **List**.

[image]

I also want to add a **delete** or **remove** button at the end of the each list item. I am unable to find any API for adding this. I am using **4.3.5** version of antd from npm.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the API for `List.Item` there is a prop called `extra` which accepts `JSX` and you can add the buttons their. For eg:

```
<List
    size="large"
    header={<div>Header</div>}
    footer={<div>Footer</div>}
    bordered
    dataSource={data}
    renderItem={(item) => (
      <List.Item extra={<Button size="small">Delete</Button>}>
        {item}
      </List.Item>
    )}
/>
```

You can also check working demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-fast-hzl9m?file=/index.js:477-755